# ggplot vertical line with date axis

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I'm having some trouble adding a vertical line to a plot when the x-axis is a datetime (`POSIXct`) object.  It seems to always want to put the line at the Epoch.  Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=ymd('2011-01-01')+hours(0:24), y=runif(25))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
```

[image: without vertical line]

Now I try to add a line at the third observation time:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_vline(aes(x=df$x[3]))
```

[image: with vertical line]

Something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = df$x[3])
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like `xintercept` is missing from the list of aesthetics in the ggplot docs, and the verbiage there talks about `x` instead. =/

Comment: Yeah, that threw me off too. The docs at http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_vline.html say to use `aes(x=whatever)`, but all the examples below use `xintercept`

Comment: exactly using @KenWilliams example I get > ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_vline(xintercept=df$x[3])
Error : Invalid intercept type: should be a numeric vector, a function, or a name of a function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently ggplot now requires that intercepts be numeric and not POSIXct. This works: `geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(df$x[3]))`

Comment: That sounds like a regression bug to me - if the axis is already datetime type, a datetime should work for an intercept.

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=df$x[3]))
```

you want `xintercept` rather than `x` in your `geom_vline` `aes`.

Comment: also the 2nd and 3rd [google serarch](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=geom_vline+and+date&safe=on) results seem to answer your question...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did see those pages before submitting this question, but didn't notice the change of aesthetic name.  The `xintercept` aesthetic is missing from the docs, I'll see if I can submit a doc patch.

Comment: But I can't figure out what generates the aesthetic listings in the docs, it doesn't seem to be anything in https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-vline.r .